# ASP.NET MVC 3 WebGrid, preserve the paging and define the route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am start to learn the MVC3, But i have some problem on WebGrid,

The Controller name is TestController, so i navigate to : 
http://localhost:53503/Test/

And the Webgrid shown as below:

[image]

two column : ID and Name.
the 3rd & 4th column : Actionlink and  item.GetSelectLink.

The first problem is :
Assume i viewing page 3 of webgrid, and press the ActionLink,after go-thought the TestContoller's Action, the webgrid will return to page 1 after PostBack.

However,if i press the [View(GetSelectLink)] on right end:
(e.g. http://localhost:53503/Test/?gridItems_page=3&gridItems_selectedRow=3
It works.

So, i should use ActionLink or GetSelectLink for general Add/Update/Delete operation?

MVC3 hasn't viewstate / control state, so how can i preserve the current page selection after PostBack?

The second problem is :
The (href) of ActionLink is : 
http://localhost:53503/Test/GetSelection/7?Name=PSP

I would make it to
http://localhost:53503/Test/GetSelection/7/PSP

I add a new route to global.asax, but it is no luck.

Thanks you very much for help.

It is my code:

**Views/Test/Index.cshtml**

```
@model List<MvcContract.Controllers.Products>

@{
    System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid grid = new System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid(
        source: Model,
        canPage: true,
        rowsPerPage: 3,
        fieldNamePrefix: "gridItems_",
        pageFieldName: "page",
        selectionFieldName: "selectedRow"
       );
}

@{      
    if (Model != null)
    {
    @grid.GetHtml(
                columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("ID"),
                grid.Column("Name"),
                        grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("View(ActionLink)", "GetSelection", new { ID = item.ID, Name = item.Name })),
                        grid.Column(format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink("View(GetSelectLink)"))
               )
               );
     }
}
```

**Controllers/TestController.cs**

```
namespace MvcContract.Controllers
{
    public class Products
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Products> GetItems()
        {
            List<Products> items = new List<Products>(); 
            items.Add(new Products() { ID = "1", Name = "PS3" });
            items.Add(new Products() { ID = "2", Name = "XBox360" });
            items.Add(new Products() { ID = "3", Name = "Wii" });
            items.Add(new Products() { ID = "4", Name = "Saturn" });
            items.Add(new Products() { ID = "5", Name = "Dreamcast" });
            items.Add(new Products() { ID = "6", Name = "NDS" });
            items.Add(new Products() { ID = "7", Name = "PSP" });
            items.Add(new Products() { ID = "8", Name = "NeoGeo" });
            items.Add(new Products() { ID = "9", Name = "3DO" });
            items.Add(new Products() { ID = "10", Name = "Playdia" });
            return items;
        }
    }

    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        //Bind data to WebGrid
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Products products = new Products();
            return View(products.GetItems());
        }

        //Some Logic
        public ActionResult GetSelection(string ID, string Name)
        {
            string SelectedID = ID;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

**RegisterRoutes() in Global.asax.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Test_GetSelection", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Test", action = "GetSelection", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343962/asp-net-mvc3-webgrid-and-paging). I think one of several solutions there may solve your issue.

Since its been a whole year since you posted this, please post an answer if you figured it out another way.